# Yii2 запуск скрипта после подгрузки Pjax

Tags: yii2, pjax

Я использую Pjax. Как мне сделать так, что бы скрипт срабатывал после каждой смены контента?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {

  $('#loading').show()

})
```

{projec root}/vendor/bower/yii2-pjax/README.md

если у вас много js кода, то его надо поместить в отдельный файл и подключить через asset.
Но если буквально пара строк сойдет такой вариант, для view  на пример.

```
$js=<<<JS
 $(document).on('pjax:success', function() {

      $('#loading').show()

    })

JS;

$this->registerJs($js);
 /* если это происходит в контроллере, то 
$this->view->registerJs($js); */
```

Comment: и этот код нужно писать в view или в обычном файле, который подключаю в appassets?